# Get a word by searching part of the word

Tags: objective-c, string, swift

In Objective-C or Swift, how to get a word by searching part of the word?

eg: "I k**no**w everything"

search key: "no"

result : know

Any methods to find?

Comment: you need to add some code, what you've tried, researched, etc.

Answer (score 4):

With **Swift 2** we can use "containsString" and "filter":

```
let fullString = "I know everything"
let stringToFind = "no"

let wordsFound = fullString.componentsSeparatedByString(" ").filter { $0.containsString(stringToFind) }

print(wordsFound)
```

Result:

> ["know"]

If you give it a sentence with multiple matching words, it returns all matches:

```
let fullString = "I know everything, nothing else"
```

Result:

> ["know", "nothing"]

---

Same thing with **Swift 3**:

```
let wordsFound = fullString.components(separatedBy: " ").filter { $0.contains(stringToFind) }
```

Comment: What about sentences without a space?

Comment: There's no problem. If there's no spaces, then it's just one big word. ;) But if you mean to cut the sentence by punctuation signs instead of spaces, then you can replace `componentsSeparatedByString` with `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet` and use a punctuation character set, for example.

Comment: My mistake, I thought componentsSeparatedByString would return an empty array if the string you passed as parameter isn't found. But it returns the original string, neat :)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *fullString = @"I know everything";
NSString *stringToFind = @"no";

NSArray *components = [fullString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

for (NSString *word in components)
{
  NSRange range = [word rangeOfString:stringToFind options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
  if (range.location != NSNotFound)
  {
    NSLog(@"word we are looking for: %@", word);
  }
  else
  {
    NSLog(@"word %@ not contains substring", word);
  }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question: The OP wants to get the whole word which contains the search string, not just `contains/does not contain`

Comment: it's just the concept, SaRaVaNaN can do with it everything that he want

Answer (score 0):

```
let testString = "I know everything, nothing else"
let testWord = "no"
var wordsContainingTestWord = [String]()

let words = testString.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

for word in words {
    if word.containsString(testWord) {
        wordsContainingTestWord.append(word)
    }
}

print(wordsContainingTestWord)
```

prints ["know","nothing"]